# What does "teases death" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I saw on an article and the title was

> KAT GRAHAM TEASES MAJOR CHARACTER DEATH

So I don't understand, is she mocking about it because in my language if I translate it it says

> KAT SE BURLA DE LA MUERTE DE PERSONAJE

Or does it have another meaning that way?

Answer (score 3):

In this instance, *to tease* means to *to hint*. This means to gives hints or suggest something. It was not said *explicitly*, but in an indirect manner. I think I found the article and it says

> During a red carpet interview at the 2016 Teen Choice Awards, Graham **hinted** to The Hollywood Reporter that there is “a big death coming up.” ([Source.](http://vampirediaries.com/08292016-kat-graham-teases-major-character-death-in-tvd-season-8/))

Instead of *burlar*, I think in this instance *tease* is closer to *insinuar*.

Answer (score 1):

It's TV review English (or EngFish ;-P)

Translation:

Kat Graham teases (us) that a major character will die (in the upcoming season).

It also has a bit of a (cheesy) play on words because it's a show about vampires.